# Use BWToolkit through code instead of IB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm trying to use BWToolkit to make a HUD-style button.  Since Xcode 4 doesn't support IB plugins, I'm forced to make this button through code.  After importing the framework and importing the header, I tried this:

```
BWTransparentCheckbox *button = [[BWTransparentCheckbox alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 20)];
[self addSubview:button];
```

I'd expect this nice-looking button:

[image: button]

However, this is what I get (minus the black border):

[image: button]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: An alternative would be to install Xcode 4 alongside Xcode 3 and use Interface Builder 3 to edit your xibs. They'll still *build* in Xcode 4, you just can't *edit* xibs containing third-party controls in the integrated IB.

Comment: @Joshua I just didn't want to do a major workaround like that.  I'd rather just stay with Xcode 4.

Comment: Join the club. :-D Please file a bug report at bugreporter.apple.com so Apple knows how important it is to us.

Comment: @Joshua:  Sure, I'll do that.  I just can't wrap my mind around why Apple is so stupid not to include HUD controls by default.  I mean seriously.  They have them in some if not most of their apps.  It's just crazy! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call Apple "stupid" for not including every type of custom control in AppKit or UIKit that they or others come up with. I do question their judgment for making it harder to use Interface Builder to edit/layout third-party controls, defeating part of its very purpose.

Comment: @Joshua:  Well yes.  I just got so frustrated they removed IB Plugins for no reason.

Comment: Is it just failing to load and render the button border/background images?

Comment: @orj: I have no clue.  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to create the correct cell for your button. Something like this will get you closer:

```
BWTransparentButton *button = [[BWTransparentButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 136, 28)];
BWTransparentButtonCell *buttonCell = [[BWTransparentButtonCell alloc] init];
[button setCell:buttonCell];
[buttonCell setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
[buttonCell release];
[self addSubview:button];
[button release];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regular buttons in the Interface Builder and change their classes. The button class should be set to `BWTransparentButton` and the cell class to `BWTransparentButtonCell`.

Then there’s one additional problem, the resulting HUD-style buttons are too low. You can’t change the button height from IB, but you can create a custom `BWTransparentButton` subclass and set the desired height there:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.y -= 9;
    frame.size.height += 9;
    self.frame = frame;
}
```

It’s a dumb solution but for me it still beats creating the buttons in code. I *so* wish Apple would include HUD-style controls in the standard library or at least got the Interface Builder plugins working soon…

Comment: I just recently discovered that you can do that just by setting the class.  Thanks for the additional information!